# How to update Label Programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel

I am facing a problem with updating my labels. It doesn't remove the old names so new names go on top of old ones. any help with this will be appreciated..

```
    NSDictionary *arrDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:requestHandler options:0 error:nil];

    NSDictionary *vendorDic = [arrDictionary objectForKey:@"feed"];
    NSLog(@" the response is %@",vendorDic);
     NSArray * titleArray  = [vendorDic valueForKey:@"title"];
    NSArray * reviewArray = [vendorDic valueForKey:@"review"];
    if (titleArray.count == 0) {
         self.scrollViewReview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0*172, _scrollViewReview.frame.size.height);
    }
    else{
        NSUInteger x =[titleArray count];

        self.scrollViewReview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x*172, _scrollViewReview.frame.size.height);
    for(int i = 0;i <= titleArray.count-1;i = i + 1){
        _noReview.hidden = YES;
        UILabel * titleLabel =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(i*172, 0, 100, 50)];
        UILabel * reviewLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * 172 , 30, 200, 50)];
        titleLabel.clearsContextBeforeDrawing =YES;
        titleLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
        reviewLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
        reviewLabel.clearsContextBeforeDrawing=YES;
        NSString* titleStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", titleArray[i]];
        NSString * reviewStr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",reviewArray[i]];
       // NSLog(@" loop in for  title: %@",titleStr);
       //NSLog(@" loop in for  title: %@",reviewStr);
        titleLabel.text = titleStr;
        titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        titleLabel.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:16.0];
        reviewLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
        reviewLabel.text = reviewStr;//etc...
        [self.viewReview addSubview:titleLabel];
        [self.viewReview addSubview:reviewLabel];

    }
    }
```

[image]

> Labels are doesn't remove the old names so new names go on top of old
>   ones like this...

[image]

> Note : titleLabel is "Nice Product" And reviewLabel is "This is
>   Amazing"

Comment: remove the old label and add new one at the same position.

Comment: @Signare thanks . Where i want to remove the old label ?

Comment: You should store the last labels then remove it when you want to add new labels,`[titleLabel removeFromSuperView]`;

Comment: before you update the label, remove it from screen. Then add it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all your subviews before adding a new one as below

```
    NSArray *viewsToRemove = [self.view subviews];
for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) {
    [v removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Above code should add before this below line,

```
[self.viewReview addSubview:titleLabel];
[self.viewReview addSubview:reviewLabel];
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you creating new `UILabel` every time if you don't want to keep old `UILabel` text.
Let say you have `IBOutlet titleLabel`, then you not need to create new `UILabel` every time. You can just change text of existing `UILabel` in your view:
For example

```
[self.titleLabel setText:titleStr];
```

It also reduces/saves effort of setting various properties of `UILabel` again and again. Only thing required is to set relevant properties of `UILabel` in `Interface Builder` and you are done.
**Note: If you want to keep old `UILabel` as well then you need entirely different logic.**

Let say you want to show different number of Reviews every time. In that case you can remove all `subviews` of `self.viewReview` by following code:

```
    for (UIView * subUIView in self.viewReview.subviews)
    {
        [subUIView removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

Comment: because the "titleArray" has No.of Reviews & Titles ,so the x,y Position are different  so..

Comment: Okay then its easier to remove all existing `UILabel`s and add new one.

Comment: Actually number of reviews can be different every time, so in this case updating existing UILabel not works.

Comment: `for (UIView * subUIView in self.viewReview)`  
        `[subUIView removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: it removes all subviews of `self.viewReview`, i assume it only contains review `UILabel`s

Comment: Yes... where this line want to use ? Because i am new iOS

Comment: use it before loop of creating new `UILabel`s

Comment: you can also use it before `if-else` block, since you also need to remove `UILabel`s in case of 0 reviews

Comment: NSArray * review = [self.viewReview subviews];
    for (UIView * subUIView in review)
    {
        [subUIView removeFromSuperview];
    }

Answer (score 0):

You are recreating the labels each time you go through the loop.

You should create them once, in an array of UILabels, and re-use them - extending the array if you need to add new ones.

Comment: Will do, but later today

Answer (score 0):

- Please change following lines after NSLog in your answer.
  titleLabel.text=@""; 
  titleLabel.text = titleStr;
  titleLabel.textColor
  = [UIColor greenColor]; 
  titleLabel.font =[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:16.0]; 
  reviewLabel.font = [UIFont
  systemFontOfSize:12]; 
  reviewLabel.text =@""; 
  reviewLabel.text =reviewStr;

Answer (score 0):

ok - first create the arrays for your titles as members of your view controller

```
NSMutableArray *titleLabels     = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *reviewLabels    = [NSMutableArray array];
```

and then update your function to look more like this

```
for(int i = 0;i <= titleArray.count-1;i = i + 1){
    _noReview.hidden = YES;

    UILabel * titleLabel;
    UILabel * reviewLabel;
    if (i >= [titleLabels count]) {
        titleLabel =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(i*172, 0, 100, 50)];
        reviewLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * 172 , 30, 200, 50)];

        [titleLabels addObject:titleLabel];
        [reviewLabels addObject:reviewLabel];
    }
    else {
        titleLabel = [titleLabels objectAtIndex:i];
        reviewLabels = [reviewLabels objectAtIndex:i];
    }

    // do your other stuff here
```

each time you call the function, if there are more titles returned than you have labels for, it will create new instances, and add them to your array.  As you step through the array, it will re-use the instances.